# Function to write new text size on window resize

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out an equation for a small problem I'm having.  I'm not great at figuring these types of things out, but I know I've done it before with a different set of numbers.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out:

```
  if 360px = 100%;
 and 959px = 160%;
then 720px = X;
```

720px is an arbitrary number.  I know that 360px should be 100% font size, while 959px should be 160% font size.  I'd like the body font-size to change when the screen is enlarged or shrunken (on load usually) and I'd like to find out **any** font size percentage in between.

I would like to plug this into a javascript math function for something like this:

```
function widthToPerc(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    var toPerc = // THIS FORMULA RIGHT HERE TO GET A PERCENTAGE
    $('body').css({"font-size" : toPerc + "%"});
}
```

And then initiate this on window load and window resize.

Comment: isn't just a couple of if statements or a switch statement?

Comment: You mean you just want to implement that algorithm in the widthToPercent function?

Comment: @Huangism well, the 720px is just an example, I'd like to know the percentage of every number in between

Comment: @inoabrian Pretty much, yes.  I'd like to have the body size the text via body font-size percentage

Comment: I might point out that if 360px = 100% then 959px = 266%, so that equation would never work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use a bit more?

Comment: @philtune That's the point, when I size the body width, 360px needs to be 100% font size, which 959px needs to be 160% font size - that's where I need this equation

Comment: Oh, yeah, please point that out in your question. :)

Comment: @ntgCleaner I don't think there is a need to update the font size for every width. You just need a few break points to increase/decrease the font size. You should really be using media query to achieve this

Comment: @Huangism I'd like to agree, though some of the fonts will look totally off if I don't have enough breakpoints.  I thought a simple math expression would easily take care of it

Comment: @ntgCleaner then you need to find out the max width that you are resizing to and then you can figure out the max %, the stuff in the middle is just a simple calculation. This is assuming your page has a max width

Comment: @Huangism, Also, if you decide to edit the question title, please use proper grammar and be more specific.  I don't want to look like I don't know how to do this

Comment: @huangism You got it.  That's what I have there, max width is 959 which would be 160% font-size, min width is 320 which would be 90% font size

Comment: @ntgCleaner trust me people aren't going to answer your question by reading the title alone. It was specific enough

Comment: u can store the window width in a var when the page loads, then in the window.onresize event check this var and the new window width like start_width * (100-new_width), should get a percent range from 0 - 200% or more

Comment: @Huangism Your edit was especially vague and also had been misspelled

Comment: @UnskilledFreak I will try this right now

Comment: @ntgCleaner ok it might of been misspelled but I would of caught it after reviewing it more but your current title doesn't really describe your problem. Your issue is how to come up with a formula that can convert to percentage. I am just going to remove the tag from your title

Comment: @Huangism Fair enough, I got the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function calculate(w){
   //Assuming the numbers you provided and w coming without px

    var d = 959-360;
    var p = 160-100;

    var c = w - 360;

    var cp = p*c/d + 100
    return cp
}
```

Comment: I've plugged this one in and you just have a slight error in it which I was able to fix and use: You just need to add 100 to `cp` `var cp = p*c/d+100` and it works perfectly, down to the decimal.  Once you edit that, I will accept as the answer

Answer (score 3):

if your equation is linear, this should be the solution:

```
f(x) = a*x + b
```

---

```
f(360) = 100
f(959) = 160
```

---

```
a * 360 + b = 100
a * 959 + b = 160
```

Solve this and you get `a ~= 0.1` and `b ~= 63.94`

So, as a result:

```
var ToPerc = width * 0.1 + 63.94; // 99.94% for 360px; 159.84% for 959px
```

if you need more precision solve with more decimals

Comment: This is a great way and I really appreciate using the variable I wanted to use.  I've gone with Sergio's answer mainly because I can play with the numbers IN the script to fine tune them to a design eye, and also slightly because his numbers were to the perfect integer.

Answer (score 0):

OnLoad you will get the initial $(window).width(). You will store that in a global variable as I said from the very beggining.

```
var initWidth = $(window).width();
```

Then the function:

```
function widthToPerc(){

    var width = $(window).width();
    var diff = width - initWidth;

    var toPerc;

    if(diff > 0){ //window is bigger after resizing

        toPerc = Math.floor((diff / initWidth) * 100) + 100;

    }
    else{ //window is smaller after resizing

        diff = Math.abs(diff);

        toPerc = Math.abs(Math.floor((diff / initWidth) * 100) - 100);

    }

    $('body').css({"font-size" : toPerc + "%"});

}
```

---

So let's say you have 600 as initial width and the user resize the browser to make it bigger. Now the width is 800.

So:

```
var initWidth = 600;
var width = 800;
var diff = 200;      // 800 - 600

diff > 0    // true 

toPerc = 0.3    // 200 / 600
toPerc = 30     // after *100 and rounded down
toPerc = 130    // 30 + 100

//the window is a 30% bigger than it was intially

$('body').css({"font-size" : "130%"});
```

---

Now let's see when window it's been resized and got smaller

```
var initWidth = 600;
var width = 400;
var diff = -200;      // 400 - 600

diff < 0    // true 

diff = 200      //after Math.abs

toPerc = 0.3    // 200 / 600
toPerc = 30     // after *100 and rounded down
toPerc = -70    // 30 - 100
toPerc = 70     // after Math.abs

//the window is a 30% smaller than it was intially

$('body').css({"font-size" : "70%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but here's how I understood it.</sub>

This seems more like a math problem to me, so let's turn the pixels and percentages into points:

```
p1 = (360,100)
p2 = (959,160)
p3 = (720,y3)
```

Now we find what in terms of percent is `720` is in between `360` and `959`:

```
(720-360)/(959-360) = around 60%
```

To get `y3`, we then do this:

```
((160-100)*.60)+100 = 136
```

---

Making this work for any value in between `360` and `959`

```
function widthToPerc(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    var toPerc;
    var minX = 360;
    var maxX = 959;
    var minY = 100;
    var maxY = 160;
    if (width >= 360) {
      toPerc = min;
    }
    else if (width <= 959) {
      toPerc = max;
    }
    else {
      toPerc = ((maxY-minY)*((width-minX)/(maxX-minX)))+minY;
    }
    $('body').css({"font-size" : toPerc + "%"});
}
```